# Is there a common identity platform to use both in .NET Framework 4.8 and Blazor (.NET Core 7)?

Tags: webforms, blazor, asp.net-membership, asp.net-core-identity

Currently I have quite an extensive web application written in ASP.NET Web Forms (.NET Framework 4.8) which uses the 'old school' ASP.NET Membership Provider.

I am rewriting this application in Blazor Server. I already converted the current Membership provider to the new .NET Core Identity and this works fine in my new Blazor app.
But because the migration will take a while (it's a lot!) I want to use a combination of the old app with the new.

On the authentication side this means I will need to use a common account provider, and as far as I can figure out there is no existing way to use .NET Core Identity in .NET Framework. And vice versa: I can't use the old ASP.NET Membership Provider in the new .NET 7 Blazor app.

This leads me to my question: how do I deal with this the best way? Is there an account provider that can work in both .NET Framework and Blazor simultaneously (temporarily)? Or can I use Membership provider in Blazor somehow with a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's better to use the old system .NET Framework and the new .NET Core Identity together during the migration, maintain the old and new authentication systems and ensure data synchronization between the two, allowing users to authenticate through either system during the transition period Authentication.

Comment: The default built-in authentication in these two frameworks is different. If you want to be compatible with one of them, you will need to add a lot of extra things, which may be very confusing. Of course, it may be better if you consider using identity server, but both systems will need to be modified.

Comment: As suggested I now run the 2 authentication systems side by side. Alls changes made in Membership are synced to the .NET Core Identity tables. 
On login in my Blazor app I override the password check to check the password with the one in the Membership-DB.
It's janky, but it's also temporary.

Comment: Sounds a bit like updating old pw encryption with Bcrypt. Everything stayed the same until someone logged in, then the code did a check to see if the conversion had been done yet (empty field) and converted if necessary.